# Possible to create the accessible table without rows by CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

The normal table consists from body, rows and cell as minimum.
However, the making of arbitrary table responsive could be too hard and takes too much time.

Below table will be easy to make responsive with `display: grid` (on narrow screens, the `.KeyCell` and `.ValueCell` will going vertically), so it has not rows tags simply because it does not need them.

```
<div class="Table" role="table">
  
  <div class="KeyCell" role="rowheader">Given name</div>
  <div class="ValueCell" role="cell">Gregg</div>
  
  <div class="KeyCell" role="rowheader">Family name</div>
  <div class="ValueCell" role="cell">Simmons</div>

  <div class="KeyCell" role="rowheader">Gender</div>
  <div class="ValueCell" role="cell">male</div>
  
</div>
```

However above markup makes the accessibility impact because the screen reader will not understand that each visible row consists from `KeyCell` and `ValueCell`. Possible to solve it with `role` and `aria` attributes without adding of new tags?

Comment: Is this only going to have 2 columns (a key value pair)? If so I have a much better alternative I can give you. Creating accessible tables without using a `<table>` requires quite a bit of WAI-ARIA that is all!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, thank you for the comment. May I ask you to share by the link with appropriate example.

Comment: If it key value pair you should use `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements, which you can style freely. But that is why I am asking if this is a key value pair only so I can give you an example.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, Thank you! But what if we have more the two columns? This question does not focused only on two-column tables.

Comment: that is why I asked the question, twice :-P

Comment: If it is a table with more than two columns then we can do it but will need a lot of WAI-ARIA, so I was trying to make it simple. I can help if you have a multi column table example (as column and row relationships change the required attributes slightly).

Comment: As Graham has said, making a table accessible without using `table` is going to be a lot of work. Surely, it'd be better to use `table` and put that effort into making it responsive? If you want a shortcut, there are a number of options, including JS libraries like Datatables (which will auto-collapse tables and use accordion-like display to reveal hidden data).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean columnheader instead of rowheader? By reading your code, I currently understand that you have a table of exactly two rows and any number of columns, while I understand the opposite with what you say.
This doesn't change the fact that  you must use `<table>` if you want to avoid complicated ARIA, and that you should preferably do the former, tough.

Comment: @QuentinC, I am sorry for the ambiguous example. `rowheader` with value `Given name` refers to nearest cell of same row with value `Gregg`. I'll add the third row.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, using a native `<table>` is the first choice but sometimes there are reasons to use non-semantic elements and give them roles.  Responsive design *might* be a valid reason to do so.

Using a simple 4x4 table with row and column headers, natively it would look something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">col 1</th>
    <th scope="col">col 2</th>
    <th scope="col">col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">row 1</th>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">row 2</th>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">row 3</th>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>i</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using all `<div>` elements, you can have the same structure but replace

- `<table>` with `role="table"`
- `<tr>` with `role="row"`
- `<td>` with `role="cell"`
- `<th scope="col">` with `role="columnheader"`
- `<th scope="row">` with `role="rowheader"`

The following would need CSS to make it look like a table rather than a vertical list of elements but to the screen reader, it treats it just like a 4x4 table and the two tables sound the same.

```html
<div role="table">
  <div role="row">
    <div role="columnheader">&nbsp;</div>
    <div role="columnheader">col 1</div>
    <div role="columnheader">col 2</div>
    <div role="columnheader">col 3</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">row 1</div>
    <div role="cell">a</div>
    <div role="cell">b</div>
    <div role="cell">c</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">row 2</div>
    <div role="cell">d</div>
    <div role="cell">e</div>
    <div role="cell">f</div>
  </div>
  <div role="row">
    <div role="rowheader">row 3</div>
    <div role="cell">g</div>
    <div role="cell">h</div>
    <div role="cell">i</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let's make the verdict. Did I understood correctly that it's impossible to remove ` <div role="row">` from your example without accessibility loss?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. If you don't want to use native `<table>` elements, then you **have** to specify the various roles (table, row, cell) if you want your code interpreted as a table by screen readers.